# WPF Botoes agrupados automaticamente num stackpanel

Tags: wpf

tenho o seguinte probleminha:
Estou criando botoes apartir do resultados que encontro no bnaco de dados.
Gostaria de apenas posicioná-los seuqencialamente, e quando
ele chegar ao final, quebra a linha e continua..
Estou trabalhando numa tela de Bar, onde possui mesas. Então gostaria de um help ai.

private void geraBotoes()
        {
            const string strCmd = "SELECT codi_mesa_controle, iden_mesa_controle FROM `titanium`.`gourmet_mesa_controle`" +
                                  "WHERE stat_mesa_controle is not null AND stat_mesa_controle = 'Aberto';";

```
        var dt = new DataTable("MesasControles");
        using (conexao)
        {
            conexao.Open();
            using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strCmd, conexao))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
        var total = dt.Rows.Count;
        if (total > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < total; i++)
            {
                var numMesaControle = dt.Rows[i][0];
                var idenMesaControle = dt.Rows[i][1];
                var mesaControleButton = new Button {Tag = numMesaControle, Content = idenMesaControle, Margin = new Thickness(10,5,10,5),Height = 50, Width = 100, Name = "Mesa" + numMesaControle, Background = Brushes.DarkGreen, Foreground = Brushes.White};
                mesaControleButton.Click += MesaControleButton_Click;
                Conteiner.Children.Add(mesaControleButton);
            }
            //geraMaisBotoes(5);
        }
        else
        {
            geraMaisBotoes(10);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi direito o que você quer provavelmente é usar um `WrapPanel` com a propriedade `Orientation="Vertical"` em vez de um `StackPanel`, assim cada controle adicionado vai aparecer um abaixo do outro e quando chegar no final o próximo volta para cima

Comment: Sim Leandro ogbado pela resposta! Consegui resolver meu probleminh. Utilizei o UniformGrid.Nao defini tamanhos para ele e nem aos botoes, que enste caso ele automaticamente se auto reajusta á tela, criando asism, colunas e linas e add os botoes lá dentro. vlw!